# Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign() [function.openssl-pkcs7-sign]: error getting private key in C:\xampp\htdocs\this\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 8366

Tags: php, openssl, tcpdf, pkcs#7

I am using TCPDF to sign PDF, but when running the [example 52](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_052.phps) I got this error:

```
Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign() [function.openssl-pkcs7-sign]: error getting 
private key in C:\xampp\htdocs\this\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 8366
```

Could you please tell me or guide me where is the problem. I am just running the example without changing anything. I am using xampp.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the location from where it tries to access the private key. Instead of '' like in their example use 'file://'.( dirname(**FILE**)).'./path/to/file'. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by using:

```
$certificate = 'file://'.realpath('../tcpdf.crt');
```

When you create your own certificate use this:

```
/*
NOTES:
 - To create self-signed signature: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.crt
 - To export crt to p12: openssl pkcs12 -export -in tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.p12
 - To convert pfx certificate to pem: openssl pkcs12 -in tcpdf.pfx -out tcpdf.crt -nodes
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after weeks ago, I found the solution. I just donwloaded the TCPDF 5.9 Version and it works :D if you wanna try, here's the link to download that version

link: https://sourceforge.net/code-snapshots/git/u/u/u/mynetx/tcpdf.git/u-mynetx-tcpdf-5828c0d80580cbad069988e2067ad5e37e1e98e7.zip

Comment: Could you please give more information and not only a link?

Comment: This is when the `Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key in....` error occurs. I had weeks ago trying to solve it, and yesterday I just downloaded an old TCPDF version (5.9) and finally it works. I just wanna share the solution.