# Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key on Linux server

Tags: php, ssl

Maybe this is a duplicate question and asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096877/warning-openssl-pkcs7-sign-function-openssl-pkcs7-sign-error-getting-priva) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083044/warning-openssl-pkcs7-sign-error-getting-private-key-using-wamp) but this problem seems specific.

I want to connect to a bank internet payment system that uses ssl certificates but I face this error :

```
Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key in /home/zarsamco/public_html/eghtesad/ipg/enpayment.php on line 52
```

and this is the part of my code that uses certificate file (on wamp local):

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(realpath("msg.txt"), realpath("signed.txt"), "file://D:/wamp/www/zarsam/eghtesad/certs/ZarsamHonar.pem",
                array ("file://D:/wamp/www/zarsam/eghtesad/certs/ZarsamHonar.pem", "secretPass"),
                array (), PKCS7_NOSIGS
            );
```

it works fine in wamp on local (window 8) because the address of  **ZarsamHonar.pem** is absolute. However this code does not work on remote server(Linux) because i think that this way of addresses is particular for windows.

I tried many Addressing methods found online and the linked SO questions.
for example I try this code (**enpayment.php** page):

```
$prepend = "file://";
openssl_pkcs7_sign(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "../msg.txt",
realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "../signed.txt",
$prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) ."/certs/ZarsamHonar.pem",
array($prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) ."/certs/ZarsamHonar.pem", "secretPass"),array(), PKCS7_NOSIGS);
```

But it did not work out either.

this is a screenshot of related files structure and location of ZarsamHonar.pem , msg.txt and signed.txt files:

[image]

can any one help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after hours of search and try different method and guidance @Sjon and of course according [this user Comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php#88645) on php.net I found the Solution.

the finally code is :

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(realpath("msg.txt"), "signed.txt",
                'file://'.realpath('/home/zarsamco/public_html/eghtesad/certs/zarsamhonar.pem'),
                array ('file://'.realpath('/home/zarsamco/public_html/eghtesad/certs/zarsamhonar.pem'), "secretPass"),
                array (), PKCS7_NOSIGS
            );
```

in the first parameter must use **realpath** function but do not use for second one.
 because it does not exist yet.  and for addressing third and forth parameter must use absolute path along with **file://** prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You should definetly use relative paths here (should work both locally and online), in this case (in `enpayment.php`) you should use:

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(realpath("msg.txt"), realpath("signed.txt"),
    "../certs/ZarsamHonar.pem",
    array ("../certs/ZarsamHonar.pem", "secretPass"),
    array (), PKCS7_NOSIGS
);
```

To confirm the path is resolved correctly, you can test by putting `echo file_get_contents("../certs/ZarsamHonar.pem");` in front of the openssl call and see if outputs the expected file

Comment: Thnaks @Sjon. I used `echo file_get_contents("../certs/ZarsamHonar.pem");` content of **ZarsamHonar.pem** is printed on the page but same error occurred again for `openssl_pkcs7_sign`. i think that address of .pem file must be absolute. but i don't know how is remote absolute addressing.

Comment: Try `__DIR__.'/../certs/ZarsamHonar.pem'` instead, does that work?

Comment: I try it but not work.of course i found that `echo __DIR__."/../certs/ZarsamHonar.pem";` returns `D:\wamp\www\zarsam\eghtesad\ipg/../certs/ZarsamHonar.pem` string that contains **slash** and **backSlash** character that are not correct for addressing.

Comment: Yes they are fine; try passing that to `openssl_pkcs7_sign`

Comment: i cal `openssl_pkcs7_sign` function in the body a method in a class named `enPayment` that I created a new object from this class in `index.php` file. It can be the cause of this problem?