# Trying to use openssl_pkcs7_sign to sign using PHP

Tags: php, openssl, cryptography

I've spent the last 8 hours breaking my brain and trying to get this to work and I have absolutely no clue why its failing..

```
    <?
    // Create the keypair
    
    $keysize = 1024;
    $res = openssl_pkey_new (array('private_key_bits' => $keysize));
    
    // Get private key
    $pkey = openssl_pkey_export($res, $privkey);
    
    // Get public key
    $pubkey=openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
    $pubkey=$pubkey["key"];
    $data = <<<EOD
    
    You have my authorization to spend $10,000 on dinner expenses.
    
    The CEO
    EOD;
    // save message to file
    $fp = fopen("msg.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
    $prepend = "file:/";
    $file =  $prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/msg.txt";
    $enc =  $prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/enc.txt";
    openssl_pkcs7_sign($file,$enc,$pubkey,array($privkey," "),array(),PKCS7_BINARY);
   ?>
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is to be able to sign the msg using the dynamically generated key.

I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting cert

This strikes me as super weird as the cert is being passed as plaintext into the respective $publickey and $privatekey variables.

So really not sure what is going wrong here..

Any suggestions ?

Comment: maybe the files do not exist?

Comment: PS: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805518/warning-openssl-pkcs7-sign-error-getting-private-key-on-linux-server

Comment: `$prepend = "file://";` with two slashes