# openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key

Tags: php, tcpdf

When trying to use TCPDF to generate a pdf and sign it, i get the error:

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key.
```

and:

```
Undefined offset: 1 in ..\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 7604
```

I have found the following stackoverflow posts and tried to follow their solutions:

- [Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key using WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083044/warning-openssl-pkcs7-sign-error-getting-private-key-using-wamp)
- [Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign() [function.openssl-pkcs7-sign]: error getting private key in C:\xampp\htdocs\this\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 8366](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096877/warning-openssl-pkcs7-sign-function-openssl-pkcs7-sign-error-getting-priva)

Unfortunately, nothing works.

I have tried to use:

```
$certificate = "file://" . getcwd() . "/objects/dummy_cert.cert";
```

or

```
$certificate = "file://" . __DIR__ "/objects/dummy_cert.cert";
```

or writing the absolute path by hand.

My script is executed from the project root path, from which `/objects/` is the next folder in which my `dummy_cert.cert` lies.

What is happening here and how can i fix this?

I even logged the content of $certificate to be sure it generates the correct path. The generated path, copied into Google Chrome address bar, immediately loads the content of the .cert file.

Answer (score 7):

You need the 'file://' prefix and the realpath to file:

```
//in your case
$certificate = 'file://'.realpath('/objects/dummy_cert.cert');
// OR for other cases
$certificate = 'file://'.realpath('../upper_folder/objects/dummy_cert.cert');
// OR
$certificate = 'file://'.realpath('C:/objects/dummy_cert.cert');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me in an online linux server:

```
 $certificate = 'file://'. __DIR__ .'/your/relative/path/to/this/file/tcpdf.crt';

 $info = array(
                  'Name' => 'TCPDF',
                  'Location' => 'Office',
                  'Reason' => 'Testing TCPDF',
                  'ContactInfo' => 'http://www.tcpdf.org',
                  );
    $pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'tcpdfdemo', '', 2, $info);
```

Notice that you are missing a point after the "DIR__ "
Also, I used the test .crt file that goes as an example in TCPDF library with password "tcpdfdemo". I think is better to test first with that file, to make sure that the problem is not related to your crt.